# I am getting class cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Below is the code. I am getting TabbedActivity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener exception. I've tried many options, but couldn't solve this. Any help would be helpful.

I've imported all the required imports and implemented all the necessary methods. But still no luck.

```
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

    public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
            LocationListener {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(10 * 1000)        
                    .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                            if (location == null) {
                                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
                            }
                      }
                 }
            }                    
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
            else {
                //
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Sorry.. couldn't upload..Check the code now